# How to get a specific value which is displayed in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

In my project, I've a database in which I've a table called Student. In that table I've attributes as ROLL_NO, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, CONTACT, CLASS_NAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL_ID, GENDER.
I'm reading all students data from database and showing only "FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME and ROLL_NO" in a listview. The code is as follows:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_student_list);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all students.."); 
    List<Student> studs = db.getAllStudents(); 

    for (Student cn : studs) {
 // Writing values to map
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("firstname", cn.getFirstname());
        map.put("lastname", cn.getLastname());
        map.put("roll", Integer.toString(cn.getRoll_no()));

        Items.add(map); 
    }


    // Adding Items to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, Items,
            R.layout.studname_listview, new String[] { "firstname", "lastname", "roll" },
            new int[] {R.id.firstname, R.id.lastname, R.id.rollnumber }); <---- this 
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I click on a particular listview item, I want to get the value that will be going inside "R.id.rollnumber". I've implemented setOnItemClickListener on listview and it's working but I don't know how to get the value that will be shown on the textview "R.id.rollnumber" whenever I click on any item of the listview.

This is my listview elements xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:text="sameer"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstname"
    android:text="waskar"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rollnumber" <!-- the value which will be displayed in here -->
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap? you should create special class for student info and override OnItemClick method for adapter

Comment: TextView rollno = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rollnumber);
 String rollNo= rollno.getText().toString();

did this inside the onItemClickListener ... JOB DONE :)
Thanks for the support guys!

Comment: @overlord if my answer was useful for you, please vote))